# How can I set a breakpoint and have the code stop on a line inside an AttachedCommand?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, command, delegatecommand

In my **XAML** I have this **command** (which is an AttachedCommand which I got from [http://marlongrech.wordpress.com](http://marlongrech.wordpress.com/2008/12/13/attachedcommandbehavior-v2-aka-acb/)):

```
<TextBlock Text="Edit Test Customer">
    <Commands:CommandBehaviorCollection.Behaviors>
        <Commands:BehaviorBinding Event="MouseLeftButtonDown" 
                                   Command="{Binding ClickEditTestCustomer}"/>
    </Commands:CommandBehaviorCollection.Behaviors>
</TextBlock>
```

Then in the command, if I set a **breakpoint** inside the **ExecuteDelegate** code, e.g. on "the "layoutManger..." line, it doesn't stop on the breakpoint even though that code is executed (I see my view):

```
ClickEditTestCustomer = new SimpleCommand
{
    ExecuteDelegate = parameterValue =>
    {
        LayoutManager layoutManager = container.Resolve<LayoutManager>();
        layoutManager.DisplayViewAsPane("EditCustomer", "Edit Customer", new EditCustomerView());
    }
};
```

**How can I set a breakpoint and have the code stop on a line inside an AttachedCommand?**

Comment: That's odd, you can normally set a breakpoint on the first line in the delegate method and it'll execute.  Is this new, or has it always been this way for you?  Tried restarting VS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work without any problem.  If you are 100% sure that the LayoutManager line is actually running then it may be a problem with the debugging feature just my code (JMC).  Try disabling JMC and running the scenario again

- Tools -> Option -> Debugging -> General
- Uncheck "Enable Just My Code"

Comment: that wasn't the solution but +1 for interesting to know

Answer (score 0):

The answer was that I had inadvertently copied in the event handler **ClickEditTestCustomer** in **twice**, which surprisingly didn't produce an error and quietly executed only the second instance:

```
ClickEditTestCustomer = new SimpleCommand
{
    ExecuteDelegate = parameterValue =>
    {
        LayoutManager layoutManager = container.Resolve<LayoutManager>();
        layoutManager.DisplayViewAsPane("EditCustomer", "Edit Customer", new EditCustomerView());
    }
};

ClickEditTestCustomer = new SimpleCommand
{
    ExecuteDelegate = parameterValue =>
    {
        LayoutManager layoutManager = container.Resolve<LayoutManager>();
        layoutManager.DisplayViewAsPane("EditCustomer", "Edit Customer", new EditCustomerView());
    }
};
```